# Node + Passport - How to implement JWT Role Based Auth on different routes?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

i need to perform role based auth.

- I am generating a JWT token with the payload that contains data about a specific customer. For example, if they are allowed to use the `document` & `face` feature.
- I have created a passport.middleware which verifies the jwt token, fine.
- I am applying this jwt middleware to my routes, fine.

HOWEVER,

- for the `/document` route i want to add a guard here to check if the jwt payload has `idcheck.document == true`.
- Similarly a user can only call the `/face`endpoint if `idcheck.face == true`

At the moment i am only checking if the jwt is valid. Each endpoint should be guarded to check the token is valid AND whether they have the role to access the endpoint. How can i extend my code to implement this, what is the best way here.

---

**1. /auth/token** ( Generating a JWT Token)

```
   const payload = {
        idcheck: {
            productId,
            document: true,
            face: false,
        },
    };

    const signOptions = {
        issuer:  this.config.jwt.issuer,
        subject:  productId,
        audience:  this.config.jwt.audience,
        expiresIn:  "730d",
        algorithm:  "RS256",
    };

    const token = jwt.sign(payload, this.config.jwt.privateKey.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"), signOptions);
```

**2. passport.middleware.js**

```
private jwtStrategy(): void {

        const verifyOptions: StrategyOptions = {

            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            secretOrKey: this.config.jwt.publicKey.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
            issuer:  this.config.jwt.issuer,
            audience:  this.config.jwt.audience,
            algorithms:  ["RS256"],
        };

        this.passport.use(new Strategy(verifyOptions, (jwtPayload, done) => {

            if (jwtPayload.idcheck === undefined) {
                console.log("no idcheck present");
                return done(null, false);
            }

            console.log("idcheck present", jwtPayload);
            return done(null, jwtPayload );
        }));
}
```

**3. routes.js**

```
 this.jwtGuard = PassportMiddleware.authenticate("jwt", { session: false });

 this.router.post("/document", this.jwtGuard, this.controller.document);
 this.router.post("/face", this.jwtGuard, this.controller.face);
```

Comment: Please don't be scared by the typescript, i will accept an answer written in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passport authentication middleware adds in your case the `jwtPayload` to your `req.user` property for use in the next middleware http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/

```
const checkDocsMiddleware = (req, res, next) =>  {
     if(req.user && !req.user.idCheck.document) {
       next(new Error('Document is false'))
     } else {
       next()
     }
}

this.router.post("/document", this.jwtGuard, checkDocsMiddleware, this.controller.document);
```

I would personally add a middleware per rule you wanted to add.